# Python - Plotting histogram of a for loop for dice rolls

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a histogram for the sum of 20 dice rolls when the simulation is ran 1000 times.

```
def dice(n):
total = 0
for i in range(1000):
    total += random.randint(1, 6)
    plt.hist(total)
    plt.title('Outcome of 20 Rolls')
return total
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def roll(n):
    outcomes = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]
    return sum(outcomes)

rolls = 20
simu = 1000
sums = [roll(rolls) for _ in range(simu)]

plt.hist(sums, bins=40)
plt.title(f"Sum of {rolls} rolls ({simu} times)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main():
    import random
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    #create a list of 20 random numbers between 1 and 6
    dice_rolls = []
    for i in range(1000):
        dice_rolls.append(sum(random.sample(range(1,7),20)))
    #plot a histogram of the list
    plt.hist(dice_rolls,bins=range(2,38))
    plt.xlabel('Sum of 20 dice rolls')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.title('Histogram of Sum of 20 dice rolls')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks very much. However, I'm trying to get the sum of the rolls not just the single outcome

Comment: @tnsh12 try the edited version!